# Updating Backbone view items when the items don't have IDs

Tags: backbone.js

I have an app with a calendar page. On that page I have elements that represent appointments. Here's how I've been going about displaying the appointments up until now:

1. Print all elements onto the page, each one with `position: absolute`.
2. Iterate over the elements, taking each element's `appointment_id` and setting that element's `top` attribute based on how late in the day that appointment starts.

In other words, I dump all the appointments on top of each other at `top: 0`, `left: 0`, then I move each appointment vertically to the correct position. (It's a multi-person schedule calendar, not a regular wall calendar.) I do something similar to arrange the appointments into columns, but that's not important right now.

Here's my problem: on the initial page load, everything works fine because every appointment element has an id associated with it. **When I update an appointment, though, its ID gets wiped out and that appointment gets missed when I do my rearranging. It just sticks in the upper left.**

The reason this is happening is clear and makes sense. I just don't know what to do about it. **In Backbone, how can I refer to an element if I can't use its model's ID?**

To make things more complicated, none of this rearrangement works at all unless I do it *after* the view is rendered - in other words, I have to do the rearrangement in the router. This seems wrong, and in the scope of the router, I no longer have access to the individual elements. I only have access to the collection that contains the appointment models, and I can only match each model to its element if its element knows its own appointment ID which, after updating, it doesn't!

Hopefully that all makes sense. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each DOM element that represents an appointment should be a separate view that has an Appointment model bound.

When Appointment model changes, all you need to do is to re-render that single view (recalculating only one position and making less DOM operations).

AppointmentView:

```
AppointmentView = Backbone.View.extend
    # model: Appointment
    tagName: "div"
    events: {}

    initialize: ->
        @model.on 'change:time', @render, @

    render: ->
        # calculate the position and append to the DOM
        # you can take a look at setElement function, if needed - http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement
```